# Haven't gotten it (riddle)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

If you've seen me in real life you would have pulled me,
but that's the end of me literally.
If you've got it here you'll know
that it might not look good on you, but it's hard to get though.
However, maybe to some of the others,
it's an achievement to those collectors.
If you had tripped in the beginning, it's fine.
The more important question is, who am I?

Hints!!!

> In line 1, I wrote 'If you've seen me in real life', yet in line 4 I wrote 'If you've got it here'... what could it mean?
> More hints coming soon

Comment: Based on the hint, it could be a _GOLD BADGE_  that one can get in Stack Exchange site(s) :-)

Comment: _really_ close, but a little off track. @MeaCulpaNay

Comment: It’s concidered good form to wait until the next day before posting hints, we have people in many time zones, so it’s nice if everyone gets a shot. (Oh, and nice question, by the way. The intended answer does indeed fit some clues better than mine.  I think I had a better fit on the real life part, though :-)

Comment: @Bass ok will keep this in mind thank you! But for the real life part, I placed a 'literally' in the end of line 2, trying to say that 'weed' really is the end of 'tumbleweed'. I will try to improve on the way I give the clues though, and thank you for the comment! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you a lonesome

> Tumbleweed

If you've seen me in real life you would have pulled me, but that's the end of me literally.

> Pulling referring to the plant name ending weed.

If you've got it here you'll know that it might not look good on you, but it's hard to get though.

> The Tumbleweed badge is awarded for a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week. That would be underwhelming and doesn't happen often on SE.

However, maybe to some of the others, it's an achievement to those collectors.

> A rare badge for interested collectors.

If you had tripped in the beginning, it's fine. The more important question is, who am I?

> A trip leading to a tumble, fine as it starts the possible answer tumbleweed.

Title: Haven't gotten it (riddle)

> No one has yet achieved this on PSE.

This answer is really rolling on from ideas from Bass and MeaCulpaNea.

Comment: Yup! Great job!

Answer (score 9):

It could conceivably be

> **a tick**

If you've seen me in real life you would have pulled me,

> ticks transmit diseases, so it you see one thats bitten into skin, it's important to pull it out with [the proper kind of tweezers](https://www.amazon.com/slp/tick-tweezers-for-humans/sr484jzrhx9a9wu)

but that's the end of me literally.

> This kills the tick.

If you've got it here you'll know

> You'll get a notification if you earn a green tick on SE

it might not look good on you, but it's hard to get though.

> Too much of that pesky green on the user page is so very ugly, but that only bothers those few that get their answer accepted

However, maybe to some of the others,
it's an achievement to those collectors.

> If you are into collecting badges, there are several [achievement badges](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges) that are awarded only if you get the tick

If you had tripped in the beginning, it's fine.

> The shape of the tick mark can be described as "after you go down, you rise up again"

The more important question is, who am I?

---

The title might refer to the fact that as of the time this important question was posted,

> OP had posted [two answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49265/karis-yuen?tab=answers), neither of which has gotten the tick.

Comment: A very good answer, hope this is the right one. :)

Comment: A really great answer really! And Maniraj was putting a lot of peer pressure... but that was not what I had in mind really, I mean, in line 4, green ticks are good on you, no matter how much they clutter up your page :) but a really good try!! and I realised a miscommunication (sorry!!) so I'm going to add a word to the riddle.

Comment: You're on the right track though.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT (based on the given hints)**

Perhaps these are the words describing a

> GOLD badge that one can get in Stack Exchange sites

As,

> A collector has an urge to keep a collection of more gold badges as compared to others.

By

> In real life, one would love to grab such thing!

And,

> it (the collection) is usually considered as an achievement by others or similar mindset / sect of people.

So the thing of interest, here is

> A gold badge

Even

> the title says "Haven't gotten it" - as the poser of this question is expressing his/her self experience !

Comment: Good answer, but it does not fit the last second line, does it? Also, that's not really what I had in mind, but great answer!

Comment: The edit is getting warmer, but what about the phrase 'it might not look good on you'?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are an

> Emergency (backup) Parachute

If you've seen me in real life you would have pulled me,

> You'd pull the cord on the emergency parachute while skydiving because your first one failed.

but that's the end of me literally.

> The parachute unfurls and the pack is gone

If you've got it here you'll know
it might not look good on you, but it's hard to get though.

> It may look bulky on you (or embarassing that your first shute didn't work) and you need certifications to get/pack/use.

However, maybe to some of the others,
it's an achievement to those collectors.

> Some skydivers may keep emergency parachutes that saved their lives.

If you had tripped in the beginning, it's fine.

> If you fell out of the plane or messed up with the first parachute.

The more important question is, who am I?

Comment: I love the creativity!! (I did not think of this one) However, notice how in line 1 I wrote 'in real life' and in line 4 'if you've got it here'... meaning... something??